# Change style of tooltip of a dynamic created textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, css, textbox

i want to change the tooltip of a textbox in asp.net .

```
TextBox objTextBox;
objTextBox = new TextBox();
if (somecondition)
{
objTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
String processorClosedTooltip ="<html><p style='font-style:italic;color:blue;'>" + 
"comments are not Editable</p></html> ";
objTextBox.ToolTip = processorClosedTooltip + "\n" + comment.ToString();
}
```

I want to show it blue underline and italic

```
*
```

- comments are not Editable

*

Comment: And what error are you getting w/ this code?

Comment: Its not giving me the style in tooltip

Answer (score 1):

You can't style standard tooltips. Instead, create your own tooltip that works in the same way but can be styled.

- [This example uses pure CSS](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/).
- [As does this](http://shurie.com/coder/code_details.asp?codeid=4)
- [and this one uses JavaScript](http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create_lightweight_javascript_tooltip/)

Example from the first link:

HTML:

```
<a class="tooltip" href="#">Critical<span class="custom critical">
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip {
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000; color: #000000; outline: none;
        cursor: help; text-decoration: none;
        position: relative;
    }
    .tooltip span {
        margin-left: -999em;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .tooltip:hover span {
        border-radius: 5px 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        position: absolute; left: 1em; top: 2em; z-index: 99;
        margin-left: 0; width: 250px;
    }
    .tooltip:hover img {
        border: 0; margin: -10px 0 0 -55px;
        float: left; position: absolute;
    }
    .tooltip:hover em {
        font-family: Candara, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold;
        display: block; padding: 0.2em 0 0.6em 0;
    }
    .classic { padding: 0.8em 1em; }
    .custom { padding: 0.5em 0.8em 0.8em 2em; }
    * html a:hover { background: transparent; }
    .classic {background: #FFFFAA; border: 1px solid #FFAD33; }
    .critical { background: #FFCCAA; border: 1px solid #FF3334; }
```

Comment: ..your answer is very informative ...can you please give an simple example

Answer (score 1):

As guymin already pointed out you can’t style a default tooltip – it’s just not supported.

Here is a library for various JS controls you can use that also includes fancy tooltips.

There are a lot of examples on the page…

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style